# How to get the remain value in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have List which contains:(without remain column data)

```
Recive      Pay     Remain
---------------------------------------------
2            0       0  
0            4       0  
3            0       0  
4            0       0
```

And I have `initialRecieve=1` variable

How can I calculate the Remain Column in C# to obtain the below result?

```
Recive      Pay     Remain
---------------------------------------------
2            0       3  (initialRecieve+Recive-Pay)
0            4      -1  (Remain+Recive-Pay)
3            0       2  (Remain+Recive-Pay)
4            0       6  (Remain+Recive-Pay)
```

Comment: What linq you have tried so far ?

Comment: If the `Remain` column is a *calculated column* based on `Receive` and `Pay`, why you don't write a function in SQL for this purpose?

Comment: I have List of Documents in Memory, and I want to add Remain Column value to it.
OriginalDouments is List<Document>

Comment: This is not a good candidate for Linq... just use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I create a simple console app depends what you need

```
class doc{

    public int Pay{get;set;}
    public int Receive{get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<doc> lst = new List<doc>();
        lst.Add(new doc(){Receive=2,Pay=0});
        lst.Add(new doc(){Receive=0,Pay=4});
        lst.Add(new doc(){Receive=3,Pay=0});
        lst.Add(new doc(){Receive=4,Pay=0});

        int remain = 1; // initialRecieve=1
        var result = (from line in lst
                        select new {
                        Receive = line.Receive,
                        Pay = line.Pay,
                        Remain = (remain = remain + line.Receive - line.Pay)
                      }).ToList();
        foreach(var item in result){
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result would be:

```
{ Receive = 2, Pay = 0, Remain = 3 }
{ Receive = 0, Pay = 4, Remain = -1 }
{ Receive = 3, Pay = 0, Remain = 2 }
{ Receive = 4, Pay = 0, Remain = 6 }
```

Check it on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5csF3K)

Answer (score 1):

Simply do something like the below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (i != 0)
   {
      DataTable.Rows[i][2] = (DataTable.Rows[i - 1][2] + DataTableRows[i][0]) - DataTable.Rows[i][1];
   }
   else if (i == 0) DataTable.Rows[i][2] = (InitialRecieve + DataTable.Rows[i][0]) - DataTable.Rows[i][1]; 
}
```

That should calculate what you need with the data in memory.